# Selenium web automation with Xpath targeting button clicks, is there a more performant method?

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, automation, webautomation

I wrote a C# interface to go through the automated clicking of certain buttons on a job board to send resumes and cover letters. My Xpath is like //button[@title=1-Click Apply]

They must've changed their xpath to the button, because after 6 months, it doesnt perform at all. And when it was, it was taking 3 seconds per page to gather a list of Buttons and to then iterate each button's click. It took about 2 minutes to send 10000 resumes, but I have a queue of people who want to use the service, and I can't send resumes quick enough. Is there a better way to re-write this to make it much more performant or to have an xpath that works? The xpath I have now should target this button, but its not.

```
<button class="job_tool job_apply default" 
data-interview="0" data-oneclick="" data-contact="" data-job="0" 
 data-href="https://www.ziprecruiter.com/clk/horizontal-integration-f0b9b05c-sr-software-engineer-tester-
15821-f7703d07?clk=VliBhk7_SO">1-Click Apply</button>
```

Comment: Can we see a code snippet of how you're clicking all the buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your text "1-Click Apply" does not belongs to attribute "title". Try change your xpath to this: `//button[text()="1-Click Apply"]`

Comment: This will probally fix the entire thing but what I am returning to is a hot mess. This was my first desktop application project that I'm returning to... and my comments left behind is basically "LOL GOOD LUCK", "YOU SUCK AT CODING", and my favorite "LOLOLOLOLOLOL"... Yeah, I'm better at commenting now.